# jquery:click event for li under two div tags

Tags: jquery

I need to bind menus dynamically based on role, thus I concatenated string with `ul` & `li` tags.

I need to show the selected text in the label, thus I added a click event but it does not fire.

**HTML code**

```
<div id='jqxWidget' style='height: 30px; display: none;background-color:#e8e8e8'>
    <div id='jqxMenu' style='margin-left: 20px;'></div>
</div>
```

**Click event**

```
$('.jqxMenu li').click(function () {
    alert($(this).html()); 
});
```

**String binded in jqxmenu**

```
  <ul id='mainid'>
     <li><a href=#>Operations</a>
       <ul style='width: 150px;'>
         <li><a href=default.aspx?src=1010>Booking</a></li>
         <li><a href=default.aspx?src=1009>Manifest </a></li>
         <li><a href=default.aspx?src=1002>RunSheet</a></li>
         <li><a href=default.aspx?src=1004>Delivery Updation</a></li>
         <li><a href=default.aspx?src=1007>Recovery</a></li>
         <li><a href=default.aspx?src=100>Local Manifest Branch</a></li>
         <li><a href=default.aspx?src=5501>Extras</a></li>
         <li><a href=default.aspx?src=2300>Bulk Import</a></li>
       </ul>
     </li>
    </ul>
```

For example, if `Manifest` is selected, I need to show that text in a label on click event. However, it does not fire...

I tried the below code for click event:

```
$('#jqxMenu li').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();  // Check if the li has a parent .. To prevent double firing of li     
    if ($(this).parents('li').length) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
    alert($(this).html());
});
```

The click event is not fired, but, when I tested it in fiddle it's working fine.

My entire jQuery code is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var theme = getTheme();
    $('#jqxMenu li').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();   // Check if the li has a parent .. To prevent double firing of li     
    if ($(this).parents('li').length) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
    alert($(this).html());
});

$("#jqxMenu").css('visibility', 'visible');

$("#jqxMenu").jqxMenu({ width: '600', height: '30px', theme: theme });

$("#open").bind('change', function (event) {
    $("#jqxMenu").jqxMenu({ autoOpen: true });
});        

$('#jqxMenu').bind('itemclick', function () { 
    $('#selid').val($(event.args).text()); });        
});
```

Any suggestions why the click event is not fired in website?

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: Do you insert the list after page load into your div.jqxMenu?

Answer (score 2):

Your selector is not correct, you are using class selector for selecting an element by ID, also put your code inside document ready handler and if you want to get the text content of an element you should use `text` instead of `html`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#mainid li a').click(function(event) {
         alert($(this).text()); 
         // event.preventDefault()  prevents the default action of the event
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
$('ul>#mainid>ul>li').click(function () {
        alert($(this).html()); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Selector is wrong.. You are trying to access the class instead of id.. try this

```
$('#jqxMenu li')
```

Try this code

```
$('#jqxMenu li').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // Check if the li has a parent .. To prevent double firing of li
    if ($(this).parents('li').length) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
    alert($(this).html());
});​
```

Check [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/2DW9H/)

Comment: What is the error you see in the console section of your browser